# Build a frame with pointer

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to to build a frame like the below one with a pointer, in this case the triangle on the right:

[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two stacked `BoxView`s using a `Grid`, and rotate the top one by 45 degrees:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100">
        <BoxView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="80" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
        <BoxView HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                 WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="Red" Rotation="45"/>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="0">
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" CharacterSpacing="2" FontSize="13" TextColor="White" Text="DECEMBER"/>
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="22" TextColor="White" Text="25"/>
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" CharacterSpacing="2" FontSize="13" TextColor="White" Text="WEDNESDAY"/>
        </StackLayout> 
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]